# select2 inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I am trying to use select2 inside ng-repeat but its not working . Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller" ng-app="app">
  <div ng-repeat="x in y">
    <input type="hidden" id="change{$$index$}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
var myapp = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
myapp.controller('mycontroller',function($scope){
$scope.y=[1,2]
var change1 = $('#change1');
$(change1).select2({
      data:[{'id':1,'text':'Manager'},{'id':2,'text':'Employee'}],
      multiple: false,
      width: "100%",
      placeholder:"None Selected",
      closeOnSelect:true
  });
})
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: you need to use concatenation with the Id...

Comment: are you missing $scope as dependency for controller, without $scope how ng-repeat would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was actually with the concatenation. But i didn't realised it from comment, but now i got it.Here is the change in code.

```
var change1 = $('#change1'); //in question
var change1 = $('#change'+1+''); //edited change
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314696/select2-inside-ng-repeat-is-not-working-see-the-snippet) can help you. basically you need to trigger below thing after ng-repeat loaded. (you can either call function on click event or `$timeout()` function after specific time.

```
$scope.triger_select2 = function(){
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({});
}

$timeout(function(){ 
  $scope.triger_select2();
}20000);
```